# Best way to optimize Android background image size

Tags: android, graphics, screen, resolution

I am developing an Android app and trying to create a background image for my app. One thing that I found that is Android have tons of different resolution such as HTC M8 with 1080x1920 px and Samsung Note 4 2560 x 1440 px. Is there any way to dynamically change the image resolution based on the screen resolution so the image fit the screen all the time? Should I also create background image for each ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi? What about the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

When are design the layout using mostly

Normal phone layout -> Nexus one set

Tablet layout using create Layout-sw480 folder  -> set 5.1 WVAG layout